# list_consumer_group_offsets is not returning all the partitions and their offsets

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am using kafka-python to get the last offset being consumed by a consumer:

```
def get_consumer_group_offset(group):

    topic = ''

    g = create_admin()
    returnlist = []
    counter = 0
    
    end_offsets = g.list_consumer_group_offsets(group)
    print(end_offsets)
    offsets = list(end_offsets.values())

    offsets_u = []
    for n in offsets:
        offsets_u.append(n.offset)
    print("offsets_u")
    print(offsets_u)

    for f in end_offsets:
        topic = f.topic
        value = []
        value.append(f.partition)
        value.append(offsets_u[counter])
        counter = counter + 1
        returnlist.append(value)
    print(returnlist)
    return topic, returnlist
```

However I am getting the following output:
(element #1 represent the partition, as you can see some partitions are being skipped for some reason)

```
[[1, 301], [7, 297], [10, 257], [12, 776], [14, 569], [16, 256], [20, 5], [22, 262], [28, 247]]
```

Comment: You're printing multiple things here. What is the output shown?

Comment: This output represent [ [partition#, offset] .. etc ]

Comment: I understood that part, but like `print(end_offsets)`, which you're looping over to create the returned list. Clearly something is missing in the first list

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turns out that this is intended behavior.

Citation from description for the function `list_consumer_group_offsets`:

> Partitions that are not specified and for which the group_id does not
> have a recorded offset are omitted.

See also `https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/2307`